# Capture Link from onClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Our Contact Us page is under the support directory so I want to test if contact-us is in the url and do one thing an if not do something else.  "this" is not valid - so how do I get the full value of the link under execution, e.g., "www.example.com/support/cars.html" or "www.example.com/support/contact-us.html"

```
  jQuery('a[href*="www.example.com/support"]').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       if (this.indexOf("contact-us") > -1) {
           alert('contact us');
       } else {
           alert('support');
       }   });
```

Comment: why not give the contact us urls a class contact for example, then on .contact click get the attribute href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the href attr. You can get that using `attr()`

```
jQuery('a[href*="www.example.com/support"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf("contact-us") > -1) {
        alert('contact us');
    } else {
        alert('support');
    }
});
```